# mod_rewrite for PHP app on NGINX

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying migrate over to my new Nginx server however I have not been able to get this last part to work.

Here is the PHP code that requires the mod_rewrite to work.

```
 public function processApi(){
  $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['x'])));
  if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
    $this->$func();
  else
    $this->response('',404);
  }
```

Here is the .htaccess (located in /app/services) that I have working on the Apache server that I need converted to Nginx:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I ran it through a converter() and got this however this doesn't work.

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /api.php?x=$1 break;
  }
  if (-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /api.php break;
  }
  if (-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /api.php break;
  }
}
```

I read that using the if statements was not best practice so I tried the following with no success:

```
    location /app/services {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    #Rewrites
    location @rewrite {
            rewrite $(.*)$ /app/services/api.php?x=$1;
    }
```

An example URL that will be passed looks like this:

```
www.example.com/app/services/customers
```

I want "customers" to be passed like **api.php?x=customers**

Any suggestions?

Thanks!